# Disconnect all computers that are signed in to my Google Account

Tags: google-chrome

I want to disconnect all of my Google Chrome installations from my Google Account, since I have signed into Google Chrome on many computers, including some that I don't own (e.g., several school and library computers). Is there any way that I can find every Chrome installation that is connected to my Google Account, so that I disconnect every one of them from my Google Account, to prevent my passwords from being hijacked?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you have a gmail account you can click on the "last account activity details" link at the bottom right of your inbox. This will show all the locations you have logged in and allow you to close all sessions.

Answer (score 4):

Change your password. That will stop most services using a traditional login. For applications with permissions to use the Google account, you can review and modify permissions for these at https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Comment: This is also discussed here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/vaEYLj0bwe8

Comment: Also, how do you know that this will work? :/

Comment: Because the account settings on the other end must log in to be signed in. If the password changes, it will have to ask for the new credentials in order to sign in. If you're paranoid, delete the account and start a new one.

Comment: Also, I'd like to know whether it would be possible for me to disconnect all accounts without resetting my password.

Comment: Not without having access to those computers and being able to sign out manually from them.

Comment: I wonder if I'd remain signed-out if I changed my password, and then changed it back to the original password.

Comment: In the future, please specify any special qualifiers like if you want a solution that doesn't involve changing the password. This technically is a solution to the original question, even if not the best one.